# Accessing other collection inside backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model, coffeescript

I have 2 post collections and a model as follows.

```
# router file
@posts = new MyApp.Collections.PostsCollection()
@posts.reset options.posts

@followed_posts = new MyApp.Collections.PostsCollection()
@followed_posts.reset options.followed_posts

# Post model file
class MyApp.Models.Post extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'post'

  follow_post: ->
    # ajax call
    console.log "_________Index:#{this.collection.indexOf(this);}"
    console.log this.collection
    console.log "_________Followed:"
    console.log @followed_posts

class MyApp.Collections.PostsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: MyApp.Models.Post
  url: '/posts_all'
```

What I am trying to do is when one of the model changed in one collection, I want to **update the other model in other collection** too.

These collections may or may not hold same models.

So let's say if a model in @posts changed in my Post model, I want to update that model in @followed_posts too. If @followed_posts doesn't have that model, I need to add a **duplicate of the model** to @followed_posts collection.

I can access the collection that model belongs, but I cannot access the other collection.
Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you should consider having a single collection and add some kind of attribute in the model to differentiate between what kind of posts they are.

Comment: Yeah this seems much more convenient, thanks. I changed all my codes and combined 2 collections into 1. Now the problem is, I can get models by checking an attribute but since the result is not a collection, I can't use all my functionalities in my views. My function in collection as follows: `followed: ->
    @filter (post) -> post.get('followed') == true` Any ideas?

Comment: So is there any way to return a subset collection?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed my function as follows, and now everything works great, thanks again! `followed: ->
    new PostsCollection(@filter (post) -> post.get('followed') == true)`

Answer (score 3):

If the two collections are antisocial and can't talk directly to each other, which is usually good design, then you'll need an intermediary -- a global event dispatcher.  When a model changes, propagate that event to the dispatcher along with a reference to the model.  Listen for the event in the other collection and use the model passed to check for existence and respond as needed.

EDIT:

Backbone's [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) mentions this pattern:

> For example, to make a handy event dispatcher that can coordinate
>   events among different areas of your application: var dispatcher =
>   _.clone(Backbone.Events)

But in fact, this is such a common pattern that the [Backbone object itself is extended with Events](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-26).  So you can just do:

```
// In your Post model
@on "change", -> Backbone.trigger "post:change", this, @collection

// And then something like this in the collection class definition:
@listenTo Backbone, "post:change", (model, collection) => 
  if post = @get model.cid
    post.set model.toJSON()
  else
    @add model
```

Also, is followed posts a subset of posts?  If so, why not put an attribute on the model designating it as followed?  Then you could find all followed posts with a simple filter function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok so, you say there is no way to do this with backbone, I need to add couple of listeners, and propogate the event and collections. Did I get you right?

Comment: Updating my answer with a little clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Although I didn't try because I combined my 2 collections into 1, it is still good to learn. Thanks